# Speaking about people's rights

Tags: word-choice, verbs, slang, collocations

What's the positive equivalent when you want to talk about people who don't observe others' rights. For example someone jumping a queue.

> I hate selfish people who don't care about others and don't observe their
>   rights

Maybe there are mistakes it the original statement too. In general what are the correct **verbs** to speak about people's rights, both positive and negative. I'm more interested in *the informally spoken*.

Comment: I would not consider someone jumping a queue to be violating someone's *rights* as in human rights or constitutional rights; however, that person is certainly infringing on societal expectations and may be some combination of *discourteous*, *disrespectful*, *selfish*, *ill-tempered*, or plain *boorish*.

Comment: As choster says, *rights* in English is normally idiomatic shorthand for *human rights* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights). Instead of "*... don't observe their rights*", you might prefer to say "*... don't show them any respect*".

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic verb to use here is "respect". When you don't do something because it violates the rights of others, you are "respecting" their rights.